# Creating UI elements in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uielement

I am not in Xamarin.Forms. In windows desktop apps (win forms and wpf), you can create a user UI component and you can use it in any project. Is it possible to create that kind of small UI elments in Xamarin.Forms?

I will have like a dll and will add to my project and will add to my form and I will give properties that I'll already defined in the UI element.

Comment: Yes you can do that in xamarin forms aswell

Comment: @G.hakim thank you for the reply. Is there any example that I can see? Because I search and did not find that kind of stuff. Mostly they were about dynamic UI element creationg

Comment: Xamarin forms controls are typically created through ContentView - some examples : https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/ and yes you can separate them out in another project to get a dll to reference

Comment: Well, you already got the answer above so I would suggest you follow that in case of queries revert.

Comment: Thank you all. @Depechie, if you write it as answer, I will accept as answer. The documentation seems very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in Xamarin Forms world, we typically create `User Controls` through use of `ContentView`.

This can be done with a XAML part and code behind, but you can easily create them just in code too.
There are a series of tutorials available on the web, one that is very clear is this one https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

If needed, you can create a separate Xamarin Forms project that encapsulates your controls and reference that in your main app solution.